# JQuery cycle through text on click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a jquery function that will change the text displayed on click and cycle through 7 different paragraphs or divs.
as an example I have created 7 different divs, and would like them to cycle through like the cycle function does but on a click command rather than timed.

here is what i have so far:

```
<div id="content-1">Sample text1</div>
<div id="content-2">Sample text2</div>
<div id="content-3">Sample text3</div>
<div id="content-4">Sample text4</div>
<div id="content-5">Sample text5</div>
<div id="content-6">Sample text6</div>
<div id="content-7">Sample text7</div>
```

and JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
        i = 0;

    (function cycle() {
        divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
            .delay()
            .fadeOut(400, cycle);

        i = ++i % divs.length;

    })();
});
```

Comment: Are they all to changed to the same text?

Comment: You could assign your divs the same class and then perform a select by the class. For example, if you add <div id="content-1" class="sample">Sample</div>, then you can do $('.sample').click(function(){// do stuff with each});

Comment: @JohnF. you dont need the same class for that, use the `*` operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
        i = 0;

    function cycle() {
        divs.fadeOut(400).delay(400).eq(i).fadeIn(400);
        i = ++i % divs.length;
    };
    cycle()

    $('button').click(cycle); 
    // click button to show next paragraph
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pPyBG/)