# jQuery on click cycle through images in identical .wrappers independently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not a programmer, just trying to assemble a small website for myself.:)

**What I'm trying to do**:
A ".container" with a grid of images - each inside of an identical ".wrapper", some of them are non-clickable single-image wrappers, some of them are clickable "stacks" of 1-4 images - click again and again to see all images in that .wrapper one by one.

```
<div class="container">

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="content"><img src="1.png"></div>
<div class="content"><img src="2.png"></div>
<div class="content"><img src="3.png"></div>
<div class="content"><img src="4.png"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="content"><img src="5.png"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="content"><img src="6.png"></div>
<div class="content"><img src="7.png"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

**What I have done so far**: found here ([JQuery cycle through text on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676547/jquery-cycle-through-text-on-click?rq=1)) this piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
        i = 0;

    function cycle() {
        divs.fadeOut(400).delay(400).eq(i).fadeIn(400);
        i = ++i % divs.length;
    };
    cycle()

    $('button').click(cycle); 
    // click button to show next paragraph
});
```

and "almost" "adapted" it for my needs :D:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('.content').hide(),
        i = 0;
    function cycle() {
        divs.fadeOut(0).delay(0).eq(i).fadeIn(0);
        i = ++i % divs.length;
    };
    cycle()
    $('.wrapper').click(function(){cycle()})
});
</script>
```

and also this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rasa56j8/2/) - the problem looks similar to mine, maybe?

**The problem and what I need**: the "adapated" version of the jQuery code above works with 1 ".wrapper". But different names for all wrappers and a copy of the same script for each of them in my index.html sounds like a disastrous idea and the only way I can do it myself.:D I believe there should be **an elegant tweak/fix of the jQuery code that would make it work for EACH ".wrapper" independently and only for images inside it**, not interfering with other .wrappers and their images.

This is why I'm asking for your help and would appreciate any help, guys!

Comment: So you want this image cycle function to work for each wrapper which will display the first image in each one but cycle through the other images within that one?

Comment: exactly. The first image in each .wrapper is displayed, others are hidden:) click = second image (if there is one), click = third image (if there is one) etc. Each "replaces"/becomes visible instead of that first image.

Comment: **charlietfl**'s answer seems to be on the correct path to giving you what you want but I have edited the post to fit your requirements a little better  [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/21webbn6/) Is this more what you are looking for or the original post by **charlietfl**?

Comment: @NewToJS, charlietfl's answer WITH your correction (in the JsFiddle) is EXACTLY what I need. PERFECT. Thank you guys.

Comment: You are very welcome, I am just here to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following will do what you want (if I understand requirements correctly). You basically need to loop over each wrapper and treat them as individual instances

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  // isolate each wrapper
  $('.wrapper').each(function() {
  
    // get the content within this wrapper instance
    var $content = $(this).find('.content');
    
    // don't do anything if it is a single
    if ($content.length > 1) {
    
      // current is the only visible one
      var $curr = $content.filter(':visible');
      // if current is last one next will be first one in this group
      // otherwise will be  the one right after it
      var  $next = $curr.is($content.last()) ? $content.first() : $curr.next();

      // fade out current
      $curr.fadeOut(function() {
        // this function runs when fadeOut has completed
        // and can now fade in the next one
        $next.fadeIn()
      });
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px
}

.content {
  display: none
}

.content:first-child {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Wrap #1 Img #1</div>
    <div class="content">Wrap #1 Img #2</div>
    <div class="content">Wrap #1 Img #3</div>
    <div class="content">Wrap #1 Img #4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Wrap #2 Img #1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Wrap #3 Img #1</div>
    <div class="content">Wrap #3 Img #2</div>
  </div>

</div>

<button>Toggle content</button>
```

Comment: This is a very good answer but maybe this might be a better example to use [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/21webbn6/) feel free to update your answer using this is using your post with very little editing.

Comment: @NewToJS Why fiddle when the stack snippet here works just fine? Is executable without needing to leave this page

Comment: Because the OP's doesn't want  to toggle ALL images from a single button click "That I'm aware of" I thought the OP wanted to toggle the images only from the one being clicked withing that wrapper. "asking how to make one function work for multiple elements" Not how to make it toggle all. Just trying to offer an edit that I believe the OP is looking for. We will see if my edit is more for what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @NewToJS OK ... now I get it. Perhaps I misinterpreted the use case which was a bit vague

Comment: I agree, a little vague hence my questions under the original post but since you had posted this I thought rather than making a duplicate (or something close to) it would be better to share my edit of what you had. As stated before, feel free to add/edit the fiddle/source to your post.

Comment: this works, but clicking on one .wrapper (after replacing 'button' with '.wrapper'), I cycle through images in all .wrappers at the same time. :| @NewToJS' improvement works exactly as I wanted. Thank you guys a lot! Amazing.

Comment: @charlietfl, your answer with NewToJS' little improvement makes it 100% what I neded. Can you change your great answer a bit as in NewToJS' Jsfiddle, so I can accept it as an answer? Or what should I do in this situation? :) Thank you guys for your help!